# Option pattern in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, .net-core, configuration

Example I have following appsettings.json file

```
{
  "GrpcClient": {
    // Determine to use Insecure (true) or SSL channel (false)
    "Insecure": false,
    // SSL private key file path
    "PrivateKeyFilePath": "App_Data/Certs/client.key",
    // SSL certificate file path
    "CertificateFilePath": "App_Data/Certs/client.crt",
    // Certificate Authority certificate file paths (separate by semicolon)
    "RootCertificateFilePaths": "App_Data/Certs/messaging-ca.crt",
    // Maximum number of retry attempts for gRPC call
    "RetryCount": 5
  },
  //... there are other settings
}
```

Here is my C# class:

```
public class ServiceConfig 
{
    public GrpcClientSettings GrpcClientSettings { get; set; }
    // and few other properties, map to other settings
}
```

Here is my startup code:

```
private void ConfigureSettings(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.Configure<ServiceConfig>(Configuration);
    services.AddSingleton(resolver => resolver.GetRequiredService<IOptions<ServiceConfig>>().Value);

    services.AddSingleton<IValidatable>(resolver => resolver.GetRequiredService<IOptions<ServiceConfig>>().Value);
    services.AddTransient<IStartupFilter, ValidationStartupFilter>();
}
```

You see, in settings file, my json node is "GrpcClient" but the property in my c# code is "GrpcClientSettings" (at ServiceConfig class).  I still would like to keep it (there are few name conventions) but what are extra code I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

### Reference [Options post-configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-2.2#options-post-configuration-1)

> Set post-configuration with `IPostConfigureOptions<TOptions>`. Post-configuration runs after all `IConfigureOptions<TOptions>` configuration occurs:

```
services.Configure<ServiceConfig>(Configuration);
services.PostConfigure<ServiceConfig>(myOptions => {
    var settings = Configuration.GetSection("GrpcClient").Get<GrpcClientSettings>();
    myOptions.GrpcClientSettings = settings;
});
```